# Using lambdas to simulate python generators in java

Tags: java, python, lambda

I am currently dealing with an app that has several classes which are used to compare files in various formats (xls, csv, xml, html, pdf...). They are all implementing an interface that is defined like this:

```
public interface ReportComparator {
    // compare files (1 - match, 0 - no match, -1 - both files empty)    
    int compareTwoFiles(InputStream fileA, InputStream fileB) throws IOException;
    // gets a list of format-specific differences between two files
    List<String> getDifferences(InputStream fileA, InputStream fileB) throws IOException;
}
```

The specific comparators are instantiated through a class `Report` and are later used by a GUI application, that prints the results of the comparison. 
Report:

```
public class Report {
    private final String name, format;
    private final ReportComparator comparator;

    public Report(String name, String format) {
        // produce comparator specific for the format
    }
    ReportComparator getComparator() {
        return this.comparator;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I am dealing with large files I quickly run out of memory when calling `getDifferences()` (increasing memory is currently not an option). Therefore, I thought of using something like a python `generator`, but I am having trouble visualizing it in java. Since `lambdas` allow deferred execution they would be a candidate for that, but would it be possible keeping this API or at least not having to refactor a lot of code (practically writing it from scratch again)?

Comment: Would changing `ReportComparator::getDifferences` to return a stream be okay? You need a return type which isn't required to be strict here

Comment: That seems worth looking at. I will try it, thank you!

Comment: As @Phosi said, the thing you really need is lazy loading, which is exactly what the ’Stream` abstraction provides. This isn't about lambads or method groups, it's about the fact uou only want parts of the files to be processed at a given time. Note you should make sure this is possible over all the formats you require to compare, sometimes you *may* need the entire thing in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, when I rewrote it using `Stream` I get `StackOverflowError`s, because I add the differences using `Stream.concat` in a loop - and it is long. Can you think of a solution to that problem?

Comment: After some research, I suppose I could use a `Supplier` to 'feed' the `Stream`. The problem now is: how do I keep current position in the file that I am parsing?

Comment: Create a class that implements List<String> interface, and which loads each diff when needed (like what a generator does).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this is idiomatic Java, since I'm not really a Java programmer, but a nice way to do it involves rewriting your comparator as a state machine, keeping the state in some object. For example:

```
public interface Coroutine {
    List<String> getPrevDiffs(void);
    String getDiff(void);
}
private class SomeSpecificReportComparison implements Coroutine {
    private InputStream a, b;
    private List<String> prevDiffs = new List<>;
    private int state = 0;
    SomeSpecificReportComparison(InputStream a, InputStream b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    List<String> getPrevDiffs(void) {
        return prevDiffs;
    }
    String getDiff(void) {
        // diff generation goes here
        // add diff to prevDiffs
        return diff;
    }
}
```

The `state` variable is for storing what state the `getDiff` state machine is in, and any other variables that need to be preserved must also be instance variables. Then, your comparator function would just return an instance of this class.

For more details, see [the article from Simon Tatham](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) about coroutines in c, which uses a similar techniche.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve my problem - I still need a list to keep the diffs. I want to be able to hold in memory just one diff at a time.

Comment: Sorry, @DCzo. Forgot about that requirement, you don't need the list for that to work, it is for keeping previous diffs if you need them later.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now the problem is, how do I keep track of my position inside a file or rather a `Stream`. Starting every time from the beginning would definitely take too much time...

Comment: It's technically in the answer, but it may not be clear. The idea is to keep all necessary state in instance variables.

Comment: I don't know how i could have missed it :). Thank you.